# Passing value to servlet from image

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

From JSP I have

```
..
<form action="TestMartController" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="math">
<input type="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/categories/math.jpg">
</form>
..
```

In my servlet I have

```
...
private static final String MATH = "WEB-INF/jsp/math.jsp";

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String forward = null;

        String action=request.getParameter("action");
        if(action.equals("math")){
        forward = MATH;
        flag = 1;
        }
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        rd.forward(request, response);
}
...
```

When I clicked the image I got null pointer exception. I want to know why it does not pass the value where it should. Since hidden will always get the values to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `input type="hidden"` field is missing a `name="action"` attribute. Thus, the action parameter is null.